# Старение кода

Tags: c++, функции

Здравствуйте. Компилятор майкрософт ругается на функцию `itoa()`, что она устарела, хотя работает на всех компиляторах одинаково хорошо. Я знаю, что у неё есть аналог под с99, но все же. Объясните причину этого предупреждения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Старые версии майкрософтовского компилятора C клали на стандарты, придуманные не Майкрософтом, большой-пребольшой прибор. В частности, считалось нормальным засорять пространство имён функциями, имена которых не соответствовали соглашению по именованию, принятому в соответствущем ISO. В стандарте функция, служащая для конвертации чисел в строки, называется `_itoa()`. Сейчас обе функции считаются устаревшими. Связано это с тем, что обе эти функции небезопасны, так как не проверяют размер буфера, выделенного для записи результата, что может привести к перезаписи данных, хранящихся за пределами этого буфера. На данный момент рекомендуется использовать более безопасный вариант функции `_itoa_s`, который принимает дополнительный параметр - размер буфера, и не позволяет записать в буфер больше данных, чем выдылено места. Если же вы используете не чистый C, а C++, то вы можете использовать `sstream`:

```
#include <sstream>

...

int i = 5;
std::sstream s;
s << i;
std::cout << s.str();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Единственное, что меня удивляет, то что подобных перекочевавших функций из СИ довольно много.

Comment: Не совсем заменяет. И snprintf тоже.

--

Дело в том, что `itoa` позволяет (позволяла) задавать систему счисления (radix) для выводимого результата. А в Linux (ubuntu) ее (и `itoa` и `_itoa`) вообще выбросили из библиотек.

Пришлось делать свою. Если интетересно (http://pastebin.com/zaNt0Y8C), то можете ознакомиться.

Comment: @avp, странно, у меня компилятор ругаетса на itoa() как раз на то, что она взята из POSIX стандарта.  
p.s. у майкрософт она как раз с системой счисления. За ссылку спасибо, взял на вооружение.